# jBehave generating 'live documentation' of the system

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave

I've read the book '[Specification by Example](http://specificationbyexample.com/)' and that got me onto BDD - I choose [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/) to execute my specifications. That was all great.

Now my interest - I want live documentation of our application as promised by the book; A collection of HTML pages that are ideally searchable and not so focused on the *test results* but on the application's functionality.

I've done some Googling and can't find any suggestions on how to achieve this. The best I can think of is somehow create my own [JBehave HTML template reporter](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/reporting-stories.html) and define my own custom template. Of course this doesn't solve being able to search or easily categorising the functionality.

Any better suggestions? Or existing templates like this already floating about somewhere out there?

Answer (score 0):

According to [JBehave documentation](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/reporting-stories.html), it seems an HTML report can be generated during test execution. I guess it can be triggered from [JBehave maven plugin](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/maven-goals.html) at least.